# Toggle section in page when clicking link with hash

Tags: jquery, hash, toggle

I have my toggle actions all set up and working just fine. I would like to add some functionality where if you were to go to example.com/#section, that page would have that specific section open. I think I need to use location.hash in some way, I'm just not sure how to apply it to what I already have.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.press-tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
})
});
```

**HTML**

```
      <ul class="press-toggle tabs">
        <li id="news-release" data-tab="tab-1" class="tab-link current">News Releases</li>
        <li id="events-presentations" data-tab="tab-2" class="tab-link">Events &amp; Presentations</li>
        <li id="media" data-tab="tab-3" class="tab-link">Media Coverage</li>
        <li id="publications" data-tab="tab-4" class="tab-link">Publications</li>
      </ul>
     <div class="press-tab-content current" id="tab-1">
        NEWS RELEASES CONTENT HERE
     </div>
     <div class="press-tab-content" id="tab-2">
        EVENTS & PRESENTATIONS CONTENT HERE
     </div>
     <div class="press-tab-content" id="tab-3">
        MEDIA COVERAGE CONTENT HERE
     </div>
     <div class="press-tab-content" id="tab-4">
        PUBLICATION CONTENT HERE
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var section = window.location.hash.substr(1); // get section after hash from url .. your url should be something like website.com#tab-1
$('ul.tabs li').filter(function(){            // use .filter to find the li which data-tab equal to this section
  return $(this).attr('data-tab') == section;
}).click();                                   // trigger click it
```

> Note: On your code I prefer to use `.on('click' , function(){` instead
>   of `.click(function(){`

And: you can make your code looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var section = window.location.hash.substr(1);
   $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){  // click
     var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

     $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
     $('.press-tab-content').removeClass('current');

     $(this).addClass('current');
     $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
   }).filter(function(){     // filter
      return $(this).attr('data-tab') == section;
   }).click();               //trigger click
});
```

> Note 2 : if `.attr('data-tab')` not working you can use `.data('tab')` instead

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!!